# what if we do not implment CustomPaginSource object, in PagingConfig?

Tags: android, android-paging-3

I am exploring paging3 library implemented in code samples in [android archietcture compoent](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main) , I am unable to understand PagingSource custom object and direct call of function in room Dao.

In Offcial website of paging3 android , it specifies we have to make Custom PagingSource object which overrides load and refereshKey method, we have to manage logic of pagination. but in code samples it direct calls dao method which returns pagingSource. here is sample code in porject

```
class CheeseViewModel(private val dao: CheeseDao) : ViewModel() {
  
    val allCheeses: Flow<PagingData<CheeseListItem>> = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
          
            pageSize = 10,

            enablePlaceholders = true,

            maxSize = 50
        )
    ) {
        dao.allCheesesByName()  // I am unable to understand when we have to make Custom object, and when we to make Custom pagingSource object
    }.flow
        .map { pagingData ->
            pagingData
                // Map cheeses to common UI model.
                .map { cheese -> CheeseListItem.Item(cheese) }
                .insertSeparators { before: CheeseListItem?, after: CheeseListItem? ->
                    if (before == null && after == null) {
                        // List is empty after fully loaded; return null to skip adding separator.
                        null
                    } else if (after == null) {
                        // Footer; return null here to skip adding a footer.
                        null
                    } else if (before == null) {
                        // Header
                        CheeseListItem.Separator(after.name.first())
                    } else if (!before.name.first().equals(after.name.first(), ignoreCase = true)){
                        // Between two items that start with different letters.
                        CheeseListItem.Separator(after.name.first())
                    } else {
                        // Between two items that start with the same letter.
                        null
                    }
                }
        }
        .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

Answer (score 0):

Room creates `PagingSource` for you: [`LimitOffsetPagingSource`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/066ea065a431ab4fbb00cc2afebfcf3d74947a68:room/room-paging/src/main/java/androidx/room/paging/LimitOffsetPagingSource.kt;l=46), so you don't have to create it yourself. If you want to use paging 3 with some other database library that doesn't do that, you will have to create it yourself.